# CriteriaBuilder.size() and Hibernate's @Where annotation

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have the following setup:

```java
@Entity
public class Function {
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "function", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Where(clause = "type = 'In'") // <=== seems to cause problems for CriteriaBuilder::size
  private Set<Parameter> inParameters = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "function", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Where(clause = "type = 'Out'") // <=== seems to cause problems for CriteriaBuilder::size
  private Set<Parameter> outParameters = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Parameter {
  private String name;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ParameterType type;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "function_id")
  private Function function;
}
```

The overall problem I am trying to solve is **find all functions that have `outParameter`s with an exact dynamic set of names.** E.g. find all function with `outParameter`s whose names are exactly `('outParam1', 'outParam2')`

This seems to be an "[exact relational division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)" problem in SQL, so there might be better solutions out there, but the way I've gone about doing it is like this:

```java
List<String> paramNames = ...

Root<Function> func = criteria.from(Function.class);
Path outParams = func.get("outParameters");
Path paramName = func.join("outParameters").get("name");

...
// CriteriaBuilder Code
builder.and(
  builder.or(paramNames.stream().map(name -> builder.like(builder.lower(paramName), builder.literal(name))).toArray(Predicate[]::new)),
  builder.equal(builder.size(outParams), paramNames.size()));
```

The problem I get is that the `builder.size()` does not seem to take into account the `@Where` annotation. Because the "CriteriaBuilder code" is nested in a generic `Specification` that should work for any type of Entity, I am not able to simply add a `query.where()` clause.

The code works when a function has 0 input parameters, but it does not work when it has more. I have taken a look at the SQL that is generated and I can see that it's missing:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  function0_.id AS id1_37_,
  function0_.name AS name4_37_,
FROM
  functions function0_
  LEFT OUTER JOIN parameters outparamet2_ ON function0_.id = outparamet2_.function_id
    AND (outparamet2_.type = 'Out') -- <== where clause added here
WHERE (lower(outparamet2_.name)
  LIKE lower(?)
  OR lower(outparamet2_.name)
  LIKE lower(?))
AND (
  SELECT
    count(outparamet4_.function_id)
  FROM
    parameters outparamet4_
  WHERE
    function0_.id = outparamet4_.function_id) = 2 -- <== where clause NOT added here
```

Any help appreciated (either with a different approach to the problem, or with a workaround to `builder.size()` not working).

Answer (score 0):

The where annotation is in the function entity, in the subquery you have not used that entity so the operation is correct, try using the function entity as root of the subquery, or to implement the where manually.

For the next one, it would be recommended that you include the complete Criteria API code to be more precise in the answers.